# exe very large when curl is linked

Tags: c, http, curl, https

I have downloaded a compiled curl for Windows (the .a files) and linked it to my project. The problem is, the compiled .exe is very large (2,41MB) just for this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}
int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = "https://website/app.exe";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "file.exe";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Now, I assume that is because curl I have linked to my project has many functions enabled in itself/contains many functions which I don't need. Is there any way to enable only HTTPS (and HTTP by that?) and with that make the program size smaller? I have found something like that on the curl website (https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html - Disabling Specific Protocols in Windows builds), but I didn't quite understand what should I do. I tried putting the "HTTP_ONLY" in "defines" in CodeBlocks but it did nothing. Probably curl has to be compiled somehow with that option. What can I do?
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: have you tried dynamic linking to a dll instead of static linking the entire binary?

Comment: It has to be linked static.

Comment: In that case, you have to recompile curl yourself.  When you do a static link, the linker will bring in the entire static library and bind it into the executable.

Answer (score 1):

1. Compile your application in release mode and turn on all strips, compiling an application in release mode will reduce its size due to removal of debugging symbols
2. You have to compile libcurl yourself and configure it. configuring a library could be a little tricky, but it worth, you can fully customize it so disabling unused features let you reduce library size, also don't remember to compile curl without debugging informations.
3. compile all staffs with different optimization flags, say -Os is preferable but you should check with other optimization levels to verify.
4. use shared libraries as much as possible

Comment: I compiled it in release mode. How can I configure curl while compiling it to only use HTTP/S feature?

Comment: [As documented?](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md#disabling-specific-protocols-in-windows-builds)